# UrlClassLoader to load a image resource

Tags: java, image, resources, urlclassloader

I am creating an eclipse workspace starting by a java project (not written by me).
I am facing problems with the following method:

```
    public static URL getURL(String fileName) {
       URLClassLoader urlLoader = (URLClassLoader) getInstance().getClass()
            .getClassLoader();

       URL fileLocation = urlLoader.findResource(fileName);

       return fileLocation;
```

since the **findResource** doesn't find the JPG resource (filename = "icons/INIT.JPG").

Looking on **urlLoader.getUrl**, I noticed the class aims only to jar files. Adding the folder **icon** to the *Project->Libraries* under eclipse I managed to let **findResources** look into the **icon** folder: nevertheless, the image is not a jar file and so it isn't considered.

Honestly, I don't get the point of using this process to load an image, but I cannot change the code and I was hoping in a solution within Eclipse project setup.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's strange that findResources won't be able to locate a JPG file. You shouldn't add the icon folder to the libraries. Where do you have your working directory? Do you have the icon folder inside a resources folder?

Comment: the working directory is not the eclipse workspace. Even there, there is the very same icon folder containing the same files. In any case, the url I got from URLClassLoader point to the workspace dir: specifically to the bin and lib folders. Finally yes, the icon folder is inside the project folder.

Comment: This is because you're retrieving the default ClassLoader and casting it into a URLClassLoader. The default class loader looks at the class path and all JAR / ZIP files in the JAVA_HOME\lib\ext folder.

Comment: I have to add that the application is guaranteed to work. I only have to setup the eclipse env.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answers to my questions in the original comment, there are some facts:

- You cannot change the code, and it looks like it's retrieving the AppClassLoader.
- Even if you cast it into URLClassLoader, it's still an instance of an AppClassLoader, so it will look for the contents of the classpath and all JAR/ZIP files in JAVA_HOME\lib\ext.

You said that the project is guaranteed to work without to move the file anywhere, so there's only one option: add the file that you want to retrieve with the ClassLoader to the classpath.

1. Right click on the project, select Build Path and choose Configure Build Path.
2. Click on Source > Add Folder... and add the folder where the resources that you want to take are.

PD: If you add the folder as Class Folder in the Libraries tab, the JPG image won't be recognised by the AppClassLoader.

Comment: I've removed the class folder in the libraries tab as you suggested. no results.

For the folder under source tab, I have tried but still no results.

Comment: As a colorful note, I add that the same problem occurs with another folder that contains html files (help/blank.html for instance). The method involved in finding the resource is clearly the same.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the line where urlLoader.findResource(String) is executed and, in the debugging mode, open the variables table, you should look for "urlLoader" and it will have one attribute called "ucp" that has the attribute "path" inside. This attribute is an ArrayList with the paths that the ClassLoader takes care of, take a look if the folder that you add in the Source tab appears there.

Comment: The arraylist only contains path to lib and bin folders

Comment: But, which folder are you adding as "Source"? If you are looking for "icons/INIT.JPG" you should add the parent of icons, and if you add "icons" then you've just to look for INIT.JPG.

I've just tried and it works perfectly.

Comment: https://ibb.co/jbb1bB8
As you can see I've added as source the folders help and icons (which contains INIT.jpg)

Comment: The problem is that in your code you're asking for icons/INIT.jpg so the folder that you've to add to the Sources is IHM_ELE.

Comment: GREAT! Even if it's horrible you made my day man! Thanks a lot